# How is a string in a map stored?

Tags: c++

When I store a string object into a std::map

```
std::map<std::string, SomeOtherData> map;
```

how is the string going to be stored? I learned that std::map is often implemented as a red-black tree, but how is a string going to be stored there? As a trie?

Comment: as with so many other things: depends on the implementation of your STL

Answer (score 1):

If by trie you mean implementation where one character per node - the answer is no, it is stored std::string per node, hence if you are going to use std::strings as keys you can look at Ternary Trie (as far as I remeber, proposed by Sedgewick)

Comment: does 'std string per node' mean pointers or entire objects? Are they ordered lexicographically?

Answer (score 0):

You can figure this out. `*map.begin()` gives you a *reference* to the first key-value pair. This reference isn't invalidated as long as the key exists, so that means the key object must exist in memory. In particular, this means you can't have a (pure) trie implementation, as a trie doesn't store the key objects explicitly. Instead, a trie stores prefixes.

(In theory, you can have a trie, and still store redundant keys in each node. That's what I call an impure trie)

Comment: Thanks, this probably means the keys (i.e. the string objects) are "walked through" by comparing lexicographically their inner characters, right?

Comment: The strings are compared using the comparison object stored in the map. By default that's `std::less<std::string>` but you can have others.